# jQuery code not working in child theme JavaScript file

Tags: javascript, jquery, child-theme

**Added in  my child's theme JavaScript File:**

```
$(function(){
    $(".copyright").prepend("Yo!");
});
```

**What's wrong?**

Comment: `$` is probably not defined (in the global/parent scope), so try using `jQuery(function( $ )` instead. But that is a JS thing not specific to WordPress.

Comment: @SallyCJ Not working. Global scope? The jQuery library is loaded in head provided by WordPress.

Comment: Global scope means `window.$` - try via the browser's console, type `window.$` - does it show that the variable is a function? If yes, then it probably means you used the wrong selector - is there an element on the page with the CSS class `copyright`? If yes, then perhaps by the time your code is run, the element is *not yet* in the DOM... try `alert( $( '.copyright' ).length )` in your code to confirm the element is actually already there. But still, all that is a generic JS/jQuery thing - that could happen everywhere, hence not specific to WordPress..

Comment: @SallyCJ  My error was "$()" not defined like you said before. So, put my code in another file and enqueued the script. It seems there was a conflict with another jQuery library.Something with $.noConflict() maybe. I really can't fully explain it. Here is what my question should have been:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2194992/jquery-is-not-defined?rq=1 Other Reference: https://mkyong.com/jquery/jquery-is-not-working-in-wordpress-solution/

Comment: @SallyCJ `jQuery(function( $ )` acts as a failsafe if you have other JS libraries. I'm guessing according to: [jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery3) . Thanks for that.